# Использование extern в с++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Я новичок, хотел бы задать вопрос. Есть такое объявление:

```
extern BOOL ttt, key;
```

Почему выбрано extern не совсем понятно. Что это?

Answer (score 7):

это означает, что память под эти переменные выделена в каком-то другом .cpp файле. Т.е. для успешной линковки проекта необходимо чтобы в одном из .cpp файлов проекта было объявление переменных без extern.

Comment: Точнее, не обязательно .cpp. Определения данных имён должны  при линковке присутствовать либо в объектном файле, либо в библиотеке. (Ну варианты с исполняемо-линкуемыми форматами для простоты опустим). "Один из .cpp" -- на самом деле один из вариантов обеспечения такого присутствия.

Comment: это верно , но не хотелось ответом на вопрос еще больше запутывать :-)

Comment: > память под эти переменные выделена в каком-то другом .cpp файле

Память по перемменные выделяется не в файлах. В файлах переменные объявляются и определяются. В данном случае, переменная должна быть определена один раз в единице трансляции.

Answer (score 3):

extern - это модификатор класса памяти. Он делает описываемый объект или функцию глобальным - доступным во всех файлах программы.

Почему здесь выбрано extern? Ну по одной строчке этого не понять, значит, была необходимость.